# Install Ubuntu alongside Windows (legacy mode)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1. My computer works only with Legacy mode (can't boot Windows when switched to UEFI).

When I boot from usb with Ubuntu it says "This computer currently has no detected operating systems".

How should I proceed to install Ubuntu with Windows?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and provide the output to `parted --list` in "Try Ubuntu" mode...

Comment: Question is edited

Comment: That's only a partial output.   we need to see all partitions.

Comment: Sorry, updated the output of parted --list

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't format or delete partitions in pendirve cause of gpt table error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/388315/cant-format-or-delete-partitions-in-pendirve-cause-of-gpt-table-error)

Comment: @Nadiya: if the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 4):

Disable UEFI boot support .  Now try to install again.
  If not working follow these steps...

> **Shrink your Windows partition**
>    Windows takes up the whole of the drive when it is first installed. In order to install Ubuntu you will need to make space for it.
>   Press the "super key" (Windows key) on your keyboard and click the magnifying glass in the top right corner. In the search box start typing "Partitions".
>   Click on the option called "Create and format partitions". This will bring up the "Disk Management" screen.
>   [image: screen]

To shrink the drive, right click on the "OS (C:)" volume and select "Shrink volume".

[image: pic]

A screen will appear showing how much you can shrink the drive by. You can of course choose to shrink the drive by less than offered but never go for any more than offered as you will break your Windows 8.1 operating system if you do.

Click "Shrink" to continue.

When you are finished you will see that there is a lot of unpartitioned space. This is where Ubuntu will be installed.

> Turn off fast boot
>   Turn off secure boot
>    Install Ubuntu

for  installation guide [here](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)

If not working refer [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tired-of-windows-8-how-to-dual-boot-windows-ubuntu/) to install manually.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: edited @Fabby but someone down voted !

Comment: Not me...  Probably the one upvoting my comment...  +1 from me, which brings you back to square 0, but with a very good opportunity to rack up even more upvotes!  **;-)**

Comment: @Nadiya please feel free to accept it as answer if your Q solved =)