# Ubunu not detecting windows 10

Tags: system-installation, windows

I had Windows 8.1 and updated to 10 for free. I want to dual boot it with Ubuntu 15.04. I made a bootable USB stick. In installation process it shows that I have a Windows 8 OS and does not allow me to install Ubuntu besides my existing Windows 10.

Comment: please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/663333/install-ubuntu-alongside-windows-legacy-mode/663839#663839)

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Windows 10 on Acer Aspire-AXC-605, I could not boot into ubuntu
 and F2 key would not bring up bios screen so could not boot from USB ubuntu live.

I had to use Esc key while booting this brought up a "Diagnose PC" screen and I
 could boot USB from there.