# Installing Linux OS on wndows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I'm a little bored of Windows 10 and as of yesterday I could no longer access my desktop so it was time to change! Does anyone has any experience with getting a Dual boot with windows 10 / installing Linux with windows 10 in general? If so, is there any articular settings etc. that needs changing in order for it to run smoothly?

Thanks, 
Z

Comment: please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/663333/install-ubuntu-alongside-windows-legacy-mode/663839#663839)

Comment: take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/40581) Look if someone already asked as similar question and be very specific when you ask a new question. One problem = one question = one solution, that's how this site works best for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Linux alongside Windows 10 is the same as doing so with Windows 8.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi/228069#228069) answer will provide you with the information to set up Linux successfully alongside Windows 10.