# How to change a partition size

Tags: partitioning, windows

I have windows 10 installed on my machine, and i want to make a new partition to build Linux on it. The problem is that i have currently only one partition which covers all sectors. When using fdisk it let's me choose the kind of partition (primary/logical) and than shows no sectors available. How can i change the partition size and still have a working windows?

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/663333/install-ubuntu-alongside-windows-legacy-mode/663839#663839)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest/least complicated way I know is to boot Windows and resize the partition using the Disk Management, before booting your ubuntu installation media.