# Issue while dual Booting Windows 7 Ultimate with Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I am trying to dual boot my laptop which has **Windows 7 Ultimate currently installed [ Not Licensed]**. I'm following this link for the same - 
[How can I dual boot Windows and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)

After I restart the system with the boot able disk plugged in, I get the option where to install Ubuntu or Try it, as I should. When I proceed with it, during the step where it is supposed to identify the already existing Windows 7 , **it doesn't**. It says, there's no existing OS on the system and then suggests to install Ubuntu completely or create other partitions.
I'm not sure why it happens, one of my guess is because it is not licensed. I want to dual boot it and not have just one of them. Any help as to what is causing this and what is the workable solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Ubuntu alongside Windows (legacy mode)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/663333/install-ubuntu-alongside-windows-legacy-mode)

Answer (score -1):

You could boot up Windows 7 and shrink your partition [like so](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309169.aspx) & install Ubuntu on the space you cleared up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But can you also shed some light as to why I am getting this issue ?