# Unable to recognize and create partitions for Ubuntu Installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

When I run the setup for 14.04.3 LTS using the live USB and select "something else" for manually creating partitions on my hard disk, for some reason Ubuntu isn't able to detect other partitions and assumes the entire SSD is unallocated. This is explained in the snapshot below:

[image: partition manager screenshot]

The description of the actual partitions are as under:

```
C:    NTFS   91,7GB   (running Windows 10 64bit)
Free space: 19,5GB
```

Given below are snapshots that show the error message I get when GParted tries to detect my partitions. I am certain something is wrong with my partition table, but I do not know what it is or what the message really means. But this might be why Ubuntu is unable to detect my partitions.

[image: installer warning message]

I am having the same problem with [that guy][3]. I tried to use the Fixparts thing but I couldn't figure it out. Any ideas?

Here's the results from: sudo parted -l

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Warning: /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.
However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.
Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT
partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an
msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?
Yes/No? y                                                                 
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 840 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags


Model: JetFlash Transcend 4GB (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4016MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      65.5kB  4014MB  4014MB  primary  fat32        boot
```

Comment: How did you install Windows 10 UEFI/gpt or BIOS/MBR? Post this in above: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't format or delete partitions in pendirve cause of gpt table error](/q/388315)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't format or delete partitions in pendirve cause of gpt table error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/388315/cant-format-or-delete-partitions-in-pendirve-cause-of-gpt-table-error)

Comment: @oldfred i posted the results.

Comment: It is showing a gpt drive with no partitions.  Did you have other partitions before that now are missing? If so you need to use testdisk. Windows only installs to gpt with UEFI and only can use BIOS on MBR partitioned drives. Changing partitioning erases drive. Ubuntu can install to gpt to boot in either UEFI or BIOS if correct supporting partitions are on drive. If system is UEFI you need an ESP - efi system partition or  a unformatted 1 or 2MB partition with the bios_grub flag for BIOS boot.  So is hardware newer with UEFI/gpt or older with BIOS/MBR?

Comment: No I didn't have had any partitions that now are missing. My laptop uses UEFI/gpt, here's my laptop model: HP 250 G2 (Intel Core i3, Intel Graphics). It's very wierd that it shows no partitions, I have one partitions with Windows 10 installed in it and a partition 25GB for Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem! I installed gParted Live on my USB and deleted all the partitions. After deleting the partitions I created a new table and then I restarted and Installed Windows 10. After the installation completed, I restarted my laptop and with Ubuntu in my another usb, I opened gParted, created a new partition for Linux and installer started seeing my partitions.

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: If you found the answer by yourself, delete the question except if you think it may help future viewers.

Comment: A friend of mine have had the same problem yesterday and I send him this link and he fixed the problem. I think there are people who having the same problem, let's just keep it as it is.